# ld: library not found for -lGTMOAuth2 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: objective-c, xcode, linker, cocoapods, ios10

I am add AdMob to my app in Xcode 8.2 using Objective-C, and I get the following error when I try to build and run:

ld: library not found for -lGTMOAuth2
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

[error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LydUq.png)

Cocoapods was used to load the necessary libraries in the app as follows:

```html
platform :ios, '10.0'
pod 'Firebase'

target 'Prept' do
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/AppIndexing'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Crash'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
  pod 'Firebase/Invites'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
end
```

Where am I missing the error?

Comment: I found the issue. I was missing an apostrophe. Thanks.